# HashMap return method

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have a method in a class, which initialize a HashMap and put some keys and values inside it, then the method returns the HashMap. How can I retrieve the returned HashMap?

```
public Map<String, String> getSensorValue(String sensorName) {
    registerSensor(sensorName);
    sensorValues.put("x","25");
    sensorValues.put("y","26");
    sensorValues.put("z","27");
    return sensorValues;
}
```

And here I call this method from another class:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> sensValues = new HashMap<String, String>();

AllSensors sensVal = new AllSensors();
sensValues.putAll(sensVal.getSensorValue("orientation"));
String something = sensValues.get("x");
```

But it does not work in this way

```
sensValues.putAll(sensVal.getSensorValue("orientation"));
```

Makes my android application crash.
The point is to retrive returned HashMap somehow.

Comment: Have you checked your logcat?

Comment: post your exception (you can find it in your logcat output in eclipse)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't have to copy the map. Just try using the returned reference:

```
Map<String, String> map = sensVal.getSensorValue("...");
```

Answer (score 6):

Your method needs to return a `Map<String,String>`.  In the code you have posted, the `Map` sensorValues is never initialized.

```
public Map<String, String> getSensorValue(String sensorName) {
    Map<String,String> sensorValues = new HashMap<String,String>();
    registerSensor(sensorName);
    sensorValues.put("x","25");
    sensorValues.put("y","26");
    sensorValues.put("z","27");
    return sensorValues;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Almost as Rich said in his answer, but your method returns a `Map` which cannot be cast to a `HashMap`. Try this

```
Map<String, String> map = sensVal.getSensorValue("...");
```

Or alternatively change your getSensorValue method so that it returns a `HashMap`

Answer (score 0):

HashMap sensValues = new HashMap();
 Set mapSet = (Set) sensValues.entrySet();

Iterator mapIterator = mapSet.iterator();

```
            while (mapIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) mapIterator.next();
                    String keyValue = (String) mapEntry.getKey();
                    String value = (String) mapEntry.getValue();
                    System.out.println("Key : " + keyValue + "= Value : " + value);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try pass by reference aproach,

```
 void main(){

    public static HashMap<String, String> sensValues = new HashMap<String, String>();

    AllSensors sensVal = new AllSensors();

    sensVal.setSensorValue(sensValues ,"orientation");

    String something = sensValues.get("x");
 }

   public void setSensorValue(Map<String, String> sensorValues, String sensorName) {

      registerSensor(sensorName);

      sensorValues.put("x","25");

      sensorValues.put("y","26"); 

      sensorValues.put("z","27");

   }
```